# Using MATCH function without blank cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-match

My excel sheet is as below

[image]

When I use the following formula the result is **8**

```
=MATCH(5;B8:AS8;0)
```

I would like to expand this formula; not adding blank cells to range (`B8:AS8`).

I mean if I don't add blank cells to range result will be **3**

Which function must I use to expand my formula?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
=COUNT(B8:INDEX(B8:AS8,MATCH(5,B8:AS8,0)))
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this (basically, you're subtracting the blank cells):

`=MATCH(5,B8:AS8,0)-COUNTIF(B8:AS8,"")`

Comment: Alternately, instead of Countif, you could use Countblank

Comment: thank you but this is not correct algoritm. When i try use your suggestion with "5", result is 3. Yes this is correct but if i change "5" to "1" or "9" result is not correct.

Comment: I took another look and I now see what you mean.  Countif() or even Countblank() won't work for this problem.  I'll have to discount my own answer then. Glad you found @tigeravatar's answer useful.

Answer (score 0):

The following uses MATCH to find the location of the sought-after element, and COUNTBLANK to remove all blanks between the start of the list and the location of the found element:

[image]

In your specific case, you would probably use

```
=MATCH(5,$B$8:$AS$8,0)-
 COUNTBLANK(INDIRECT("R8C2:R8C"&MATCH(5,$B$8:$AS$8,0),FALSE))
```

If the sought-after does not exist in the list, #N/A is returned.